# How to use Akka.Net Cluster to have an entity on only one node and have messages arrive there from all nodes

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-cluster

I have a test actor system with customer actors. It keeps track of state of a customer. Event messages and query messages are sent to the Coordinator. If no Customer actor exists for the message, the Coordinator creates one. Works fine and looks like this:

[image: standalone]

Now I want to add clustering. I want the system to be large enough for many customers and when one goes down, the messages can still be handled be the other nodes. So after reading and tinkering a bit, I thought I knew what to do, but I must be misunderstanding. This was my approach. I added a ConsistentHashingPool actor above the coordinator (using customer ID as the key). Then by making that pool cluster aware, it could distribute coordinators with their customers to other nodes. When still on one node it looks like this:

[image: pool on one node]

Worked like a charm. But then I added a second node to the cluster. It then looked like this:

[image: on two nodes]

This is not what I want. All customers have now two actors representing them. Some of the events end up on node 1, others on node 2. I clearly had some wrong expectations. I sort-of expected the cluster-aware pool to be present on both node "as one".

So what should I do to achieve my goal? Maybe there should be dispatcher roles and state roles? But I'd still want 2 dispatchers then. Should I look into this Cluster Singleton thing? There it states that the singleton can easily become a bottleneck. Preferably, I would have a router on every node, but they would share the routees, some local and some remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, don't use ConsistenHashing cluster router. There's a dedicated feature for that known as [Akka.Cluster.Sharding](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Akka.Cluster.Sharding/1.3.2-beta54). It's already used by people on quite a few projects. There are several articles about it:

- [Official documentation](http://getakka.net/articles/clustering/cluster-sharding.html)
- [More detailed introduction](https://petabridge.com/blog/introduction-to-cluster-sharding-akkadotnet/) - it also covers, why consistent hashing is not what you want.
- A more [technical insight](https://petabridge.com/blog/cluster-sharding-technical-overview-akkadotnet/) into how Akka.Cluster.Sharding actually works

Comment: Thanks, that is clearly what I was missing. I did skim over the subject in the docs, but the summary ("when you want to contact with cluster actors using their logical id's, but don't want to care about their physical location inside the cluster or manage their creation") didn't sound like what I was looking for.